# Check if user isLoggedIn MongoDB Realm Web SDK

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm

I wish to check if a user is already logged in through email/password auth via mongodb realm web-sdk. Knowing if the user is logged in will allow me to hide the loggin page from site and instead show a log out button.

So far I've successfully created a user and logged in. Using the code/methods below.

```
    async function registerEmailPassword(email, password) {
        try {
            const user = await app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser({ email, password });
            return user;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to register", error)
        }
    }

    async function loginEmailPassword(email, password) {
        // Create an email/password credential
        const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
        try {
          // Authenticate the user
          const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
          // `App.currentUser` updates to match the logged in user
          console.assert(user.id === app.currentUser.id);
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to log in", error);
        }
      }
```

Comment: That code looks fine; you're using [isLoggedIn](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/api/io/realm/mongodb/User/#isloggedin). Is it not working?

Comment: It is working, but I'm not sure if I should be using isLoggedIn on the currentUser method or it should be on the user method. If there's no User in currentUser. I'm new to mongodb, so I'm not sure if this should be done in this manner as I could not find an example for this. If their's no currentUser, I can't use the isLoggedIn, that's my confusion.

Comment: Ah. user and currentUser look to be the same thing in your code. i.e. *you* are defining a user var `const user = await app.` but the app keeps that data in the `app.currentUser` property. So, checking to see if app.currentUser is valid, and then if so, seeing if `isLoggedIn` is the correct path.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, I'll move it as an answer in this case to prevent any confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going through the [mongodb class documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/api/io/realm/mongodb/User/#isloggedin), I wrote the following function which appears to work.

The code is checking for if their is any user in `currentUser`, if their is no `currentUser`, their no account logged in. In the event their is a `currentUser`, the code then checks using `currentUser.isLoggedIn` if that user is logged and at the end returns a boolean value.

```
    async function isUserLoggedIn() {
        try {
            const userStatus = await app.currentUser;
            if (userStatus == null) {
                return false
            } else {
                const userStatus = await app.currentUser.isLoggedIn;
                return userStatus
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Failed to fetch user", error);
        }
    }

    // Check if user is logged in
    isUserLoggedIn().then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```